# JFreeChart XY-series coordinates by clicking the chart

Tags: java, servlets, model-view-controller, controller, jfreechart

I am trying to get the x and y coordinates individually when the user clicks on one of the points of XY series charts that JFreeChart provides. Also I am doing it in a servlet using Java programming language. `List` are objects that I made from a model package that has classes called `Home`, and `Away`. Feel free to ask more information about the servlet, as I am providing the code below.

````
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Object saved in application scopes two list one fore Home and Away   

        List<Home> forumi = (List<Home>) getServletContext().getAttribute(
                "home" );

        List<Away> forumi2 = (List<Away>) getServletContext().getAttribute(
                "away" );

        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(); 

        try {
            //creating an XY dataset
             XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
                XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Home");
                XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("Away");

        //inputing data to chart
        int counter = 1;
        for(int i=0; i < forumi.size(); i++) {
            series1.add(counter, forumi.get(i).getScores());
            ++counter;
        }

        int counter2 = 1;
        for(int i=0; i < forumi2.size(); i++) {
            series2.add(counter2, forumi2.get(i).getScores());
            ++counter2;
        }

        dataset.addSeries(series1);
        dataset.addSeries(series2);
        /* create chart */
        String chartTitle = "2019-2020";
        String xAxisLabel = "game";
        String yAxisLabel = "Scores";

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(chartTitle,
                xAxisLabel, yAxisLabel, dataset);

        //Customize chart
         XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
         XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
        // sets thickness for series (using strokes)
         renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.RED);
         renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.BLUE);
        // sets paint color for each series
         renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(2.0f));
         renderer.setSeriesStroke(1, new BasicStroke(2.0f));
         //renderer.setSeriesStroke(1, new BasicStroke(3.0f));

         plot.setRenderer((XYItemRenderer) renderer);
         chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);   
        //System.out.print(plot.getRangeCrosshairValue()); 

        chart.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        /* Set the HTTP Response Type */
        response.setContentType("image/png");

        /* Writes a chart to an output stream in PNG format */
        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, chart, 1704, 300);


        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString()); /* Throw exceptions to log files */
        } finally {
        out.close();/* Close the output stream */
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    } ```
````

Comment: You may be able to leverage an [*HTML image map*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20HTML%20image%20map) for this; more [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/search.php?keywords=HTML+image+map).

Comment: I've seen others code how they use mousevents but don't know how to do that, do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19464319/230513), you can create an [*HTML image map*](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_images_imagemap.asp) corresponding to the entities in your chart for use in a servlet context.

Setting `tooltips` to `true` in your chosen `ChartFactory` adds a `StandardXYToolTipGenerator` which will show a tool tip on mouse moved events; mouse over entities in `scatter.html` to see the effect; you can customize the generator as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770477/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31287707/230513).

Setting `urls` to `true` in your chosen `ChartFactory` adds a `StandardXYURLGenerator` which will open the generated URL on mouse clicked events; click on an entity in `scatter.html` with a custom generator to see the effect:

```
chart.getXYPlot().getRenderer().setURLGenerator(new StandardXYURLGenerator(){
    @Override
    public String generateURL(XYDataset dataset, int series, int item) {
        return "http://example.com";
    }
});
```

Your actual generator can return any desired URL for particular values of `dataset`, `series` and `item`.

Comment: I am running straight from servlet and not html nor jsp

Comment: One servlet would output the `<map>` and `<img>` tags; the `<img>` tag's `src` attribute would specify a second servlet that outputs the chart image.